# how to span html table when selecting particular row and column from select input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

IF you select day and time that slot turn vertically like change value of rowspan and colspan base on selection you can view in image link in this blog
[view image click here](http://learnyourselfaboutcomputers.blogspot.com)

```js
$("#hour,#day").on("click",function(){
var id = $("#hour").children(":selected").attr("value");
var idi = $("#day").children(":selected").attr("value");
res=idi.concat(id);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
$("#"+res).css("color","red")
});
```

```css
#timetable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
}

#timetable td, #timetable th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}


#timetable th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<form method="post" action="Select_lab.php">
<center>
<h4>Select Day And Time Where you want to add LABORATORY Slot in table</h4> 
<br>
<B><label>Select Day:</label></B><select id="day" name="day">
    <option value="0">Monday</option>
    <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="3">Thursday</option>
    <option value="4">Friday</option>
    <option value="5">Saturday</option>
</select>
  <B> <label>Select Hour:</label></B><select name="hour" id="hour">
    <option value="0">10:30 To 11:30</option>
    <option value="1">11:30 To 12:30</option>
    <option value="3">2:00 To 3:00</option>
    <option value="4">3:00 To 4:00</option>
    <option value="5">4:00 To 5:00</option>
    <option value="6">5:00 To 6:00</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</center>
<table id="timetable">
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th >Monday</th>
     <th>Tuesday</th>
     <th>Wednesday</th>
     <th>Thursday</th>
     <th>Friday</th>
     <th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>10:30 to 11:30</th>
    <td id="00">00</td>
    <td id="10">10</td>
    <td id="20">20</td>
    <td id="30">30</td>
    <td id="40">40</td>   
    <td id="50">50</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>11:30 to 12:30</th>
    <td id="01">01</td>
    <td id="11">11</td>
    <td id="21">21</td>
    <td id="31">31</td>
    <td id="41">41</td>
    <td id="51">51</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>12:30 to 1:30</th>
    <td id="02">02</td>
    <td id="12">12</td>
    <td id="22">22</td>
    <td id="32">32</td>
    <td id="42">42</td>
    <td id="52">52</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>1:30 to 2:00</th>
    
    <td colspan="6"> <center>Reccess</center></td>
  
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <th>2:00 to 3:00</th>
    <td id="03">03</td>
    <td id="13">13</td>
    <td id="23">23</td>
    <td id="33">33</td>
    <td id="43">43</td>
    <td id="53">53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3:00 to 4:00</th>
    <td id="04">04</td>
    <td id="14">14</td>
    <td id="24">24</td>
    <td id="34">34</td>
    <td id="44">44</td>
    <td id="54">54</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>4:00 to 5:00</th>
    <td id="05">05</td>
    <td id="15">15</td>
    <td id="25">25</td>
    <td id="35">35</td>
    <td id="45">45</td>
    <td id="55">55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="1">5:00 to 6:00</th>
    <td id="06">06</td>
    <td id="16">16</td>
    <td id="26">26</td>
    <td id="36">36</td>
    <td id="46">46</td>
    <td id="56">56</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

```
dd LABORATORY Slot in table</h4></br>
 <B> <label>Select Day:</label></B><select id="day" name="day">
<option value="0">Monday</option>
<option value="1">Tuesday</option>
<option value="2">Wednesday</option>
<option value="3">Thursday</option>
<option value="4">Friday</option>
<option value="5">Saturday</otion>
</select>
<B> <label>Select Hour:</label></B><select name="hour" id="hour">
<option value="0">10:30 To 11:30</option>
<option value="1">11:30 To 12:30</option>
<option value="3">2:00 To 3:00</option>
<option value="4">3:00 To 4:00</option>
<option value="5">4:00 To 5:00</option>
<option value="6">5:00 To 6:00</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></br>
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['salarieid'])) {
      $_SESSION['div'] = $_POST['salarieid'];
      echo  $_SESSION['div'];}
     if (isset($_POST['day'])) {
      $_SESSION['day'] = $_POST['day'];
      echo  $_SESSION['day'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['hour'])) {
      $_SESSION['hour'] = $_POST['hour'];
      echo  $_SESSION['hour'];}
?>
<p id="demo"></p>
</center>
<table id="timetable">
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th>Monday</th>
 <th>Tuesday</th>
 <th>Wednesday</th>
 <th>Thursday</th>
 <th>Friday</th>
 <th>Saturday</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>10:30 to 11:30</th>
<td id="00" rowspan="2">00</td>
<td id="10" rowspan="2">10</td>
<td id="20">20</td>
<td id="30">30</td>
<td id="40">40</td>   
<td id="50">50</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>11:30 to 12:30</th>
<td id="01">01</td>
<td id="11">11</td>
<td id="21">21</td>
<td id="31">31</td>
<td id="41">41</td>
<td id="51">51</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>12:30 to 1:30</th>
<td id="02">02</td>
<td id="12">12</td>
<td id="22">22</td>
<td id="32">32</td>
<td id="42">42</td>
<td id="52">52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1:30 to 2:00</th>enter code here  
<td colspan="6"> <center>Reccess</center></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<th>2:00 to 3:00</th>
<td id="03">03</td>
<td id="13">13</td>
<td id="23">23</td>
<td id="33">33</td>
<td id="43">43</td>
<td id="53">53</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>3:00 to 4:00</th>
<td id="04">04</td>
<td id="14">14</td>
<td id="24">24</td>
<td id="34">34</td>
<td id="44">44</td>
<td id="54">54</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>4:00 to 5:00</th>
<td id="05">05</td>
<td id="15">15</td>
<td id="25">25</td>
<td id="35">35</td>
<td id="45">45</td>
<td id="55">55</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="1">5:00 to 6:00</th>
<td id="06">06</td>
<td id="16">16</td>
<td id="26">26</td>
<td id="36">36</td>
<td id="46">46</td>
<td id="56">56</td>
</tr>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#hour,#day").on("click",function(){
var id = $("#hour").children(":selected").attr("value");
var idi = $("#day").children(":selected").attr("value");
res=idi.concat(id);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
$("#"+res).css("color","red")
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Rohit, first just want to say good job on formatting your question with a code snippet. Can you be more clear and concise on what your expected outcome is? For example, what does 'span html table' mean to you, or where exactly the issue is for you?

Comment: http://learnyourselfaboutcomputers.blogspot.com  IN this you can see want output like that image

Comment: ok. And what difficulty are you facing? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: P.S. `$("#hour,#day").on("click",function(){` would be better as `$("#hour,#day").on("change",function(){`, then it doesn't run unnecessarily when the user opens the dropdown, only when they choose a value.

Comment: And `$("#hour").children(":selected").attr("value")` can be shortened to just `$("#hour").val()` - in a `<select` the `.val()` function will automatically get the value of the selected option. You don't have to locate it explicitly. You can change the line below that in the same way

Comment: I am trying php code for do that but It is hard create code to manage colspan and rowspan both value at time.

Comment: The Link is not valid anymore